# How can i save nested documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have recently started working on mongoose, and i'm stuck in one issue.
the type of data i want to save is as shown below,

```
{
   ObjectId('abcd')
   allData,
   parentId:null,  // super parent level's parent id is always null
   children:[
     {
       ObjectId('xyz')
       allData,
       parentId:ObjectId('abcd'),// id of parent
       children:[
       {
          allData,
          parentId:ObjectId('xyz'),// id of parent
          children:[
          {
            ... // nested levels can be N number of times
          }
          ]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

In above data there is only one model which is used recursively at all the nested levels.
So is there any method in mongoose that i can use to save the above type of data at one Go. i.e in one call i need to add above data with all its sub levels.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Best and efficient way to do this is,
Just save your document in normal form and then just give them parentId or children's id in array.

I've given example below so you can understand.

#### Using ParentId variable :

```
ObjectId('abcd')
allData,
parentId:null, 


ObjectId('xyz')
allData,
parentId:ObjectId('abcd'), 


ObjectId('xyz-new')
allData,
parentId:ObjectId('abcd'),
```

#### Using ChildrenId Array variable :

```
ObjectId('abcd')
allData,
childrens:[ObjectId('xyz'),ObjectId('xyz-new')], 


ObjectId('xyz')
allData,
childrens:[], 


ObjectId('xyz-new')
allData,
childrens:[],
```